# Changing BoundField value after initializing and validating form

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

I am trying to manually change the name of a form field after it initialized in a CBV. You could do this after initializing:

```
form = self.get_form()  # it is initialized here
form.cleaned_data['name'] = form.instance.name + ' (new)'
```

But I need to change the value after validating, so `form.cleaned_data` is no longer involved. I need to directly change the value of the `BoundField`. How can I do that? Or how can I do what I am trying to do in any other way?

Here is some cody of my view and form class:

```
class MyView(CBV):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if copy:
            form.instance.pk = None
            name = form.instance.name + ' (new)'
            form.instance.name = name
            # it does work this way
            data = form.data.copy()
            data['name'] = name
            form.data = data
            self.object = form.save()
        else:
            pass
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.copy = kwargs.get('copy', False)
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_name(self):
        # (1) doing this has no effect in the displayed form included in the response of a POST request
        # (2) I don't always want to do this, only when a form is valid
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data['name']
        if self.copy:
            cleaned_data['name'] += ' (new)'
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: How about using form.validated_data?

Comment: @seuling that attribute doesn't seem to exist in a form instance

Comment: Oh I'm confusing with drf. Try cleaned_data or just form.data - You can use it after validation

Comment: @seuling as I said in my question `form.cleaned_data` doesn't do it. And `form.data` is immutable.

Comment: Then you can customize clean method. Or, it's better to use `clean_field` method to customize specific field

Comment: @seuling I don't want to modify it at the point of validation. I need to change it _afterwards_.

Comment: If you inherit clean(), you can modify afterwards. I'll write answer

Comment: You should explain *why* you need to change it *afterwards*. That is almost certainly not the right thing to do. As others have said, the place to change the values *is* in the clean methods.

Comment: @DanielRoseman as I said, changing in the clean methods does not work because it seems to get overriden by the data kwargs passed to the form constructor. I need to changing afterwards because changing the name like I'm doing has nothing to do with validation, it's an extra action separate from the form logic and it is located elsewhere (in a CBV).

Comment: This makes it even less clear. You probably need to show this "extra action"; what exactly are you passing to it and what are you expecting?

Comment: @DanielRoseman the form can be submitted with an "edit" button which does what you'd expect, and a "save as copy" button which as you can imagine creates a new db entry. In the latter case I want to change the name of the instance, but only if the validation goes through. The whole logic of doing this has nothing to do with the form, it should not be its responsibility. It is something I handle in the view. In any case if I were to handle in in the clean method, that would not serve me either, because if the form is invalid then we wouldn't want the name changed, which is what clean would do.

Comment: OK. In that case *you need to show the code that does this* so we know how you are trying to do it and what doesn't work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman alright, just included some code

Answer (score 1):

You can override clean method. After inherit form, you can modify your cleaned_data after validation.

```
def clean(self)
    # It will validate data
    self.cleaned_data = super().clean()
    # do what you want
    self.cleaned_data['name'] = 'blah...'
    return self.cleaned_data
```

Or you can use specific field, in this situcation, name.

```
def clean_name(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data.get('name', '')
    if not data:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You must enter a name")

    if not data.endswith('( new)'):
        return data += '( new)'
    return data
```

### ADD

You can see the validation actually *already DONE* after `super().clean()`.
You can check print `self.is_valid()` then you can see it's True. Or just add debugger in that line to check validation is already done

```
def clean(self):
    # It will validate data
    self.cleaned_data = super().clean()
    # Check validation is already done here
    # Or debugging it
    # from IPython import embed; embed() 
    print(self.is_valid())
    # do what you want
    return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: As I said I don't want to set the value at validation level. The clean methods are used when validating the form. I need to change the field value after validating (and only when the form is valid, at that).

Comment: In any case, not even during validation it is working.

Comment: Ok... you have to see django form code first. (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L423) After super clean() method, the form already validated.

Comment: It's no good either. It seems that `form.data` will override any data, even cleaned data. The only way I managed to do what I am trying is creating a copy of the immutable `form.data` and modify the `'name'` key directly. But this doesn't seem like the proper way to do it.

Comment: @dabadaba I'm not sure what you really want. What's difference btw create copy of form.data / or cleaned_data inside clean()? It's why 'clean()' method exist.

Comment: In your way, it's simply changing `form.changed_data` itself is basically no good.

Comment: @dabadaba this answer is the correct way to do it. You definitely should manipulate the values of `self.cleaned_data` because those are the *only* values you should use to save or commit your form to db/storage. It's not clear why you'd want to change `self.data` as well: if the form isn't valid and you show the bound, invalid form with errors to the user, suddenly fields have changed. That would be unexpected to the user and bad UI.

Comment: @seuling the difference is that changing `self.cleaned_data` seems to have no effect in the displayed form, however passing the data dict that is passed does

Answer (score 0):

You should save the form first, with `commit=False`, and then change it in the instance.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if copy:
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.pk = None
        name = instance.name + ' (new)'
        instance.save()
        return...
```

(Also, you should always redirect after a successful post, not render a template.)

Comment: How do I prevent the change in case the form is invalid? (right, I just mocked the code, my actual returned response is json)

Comment: Well `form_valid` wouldn't be called when the form is not valid.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If so please accept the answer, as a sign to future searchers.

Comment: I haven't had the chance to try it yet. Don't worry I will accept it if it solved the problem.

Comment: This isn't doing it either. Sure it's saving the instance with the changed named (it was doing this correctly already anyway), but it's not loading the form in the successful response with the correct name in the name field.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to happen there. Like I said, you should always redirect after a successful post. Perhaps you want to redirect for the update page for the new item?

Comment: I am not redirecting, I am returning the same (updated) form in a json response.

Comment: So this is an Ajax view? How are you generating that response? How are you serializing the form? Perhaps you should just instantiate a new form from the new instance.

Comment: Right, that's a good idea. However, when when instantiating a form using the CBV method `self.get_form()`, data in `self.request.POST` is update the kwargs dict used to initialize the form, so we end up overriding the form we include in the response. I guess the solution here would be to override `self.get_form_kwargs` when we want a fresh form? Or rather to instantiate the form directly before responding, without using `self.get_form()`?

Comment: Alright I have tried this, but it seems that if you only pass `instance` and not `data` to the form constructor, it just won't load that value in the bound field.